# How to create multiple checkbox from API in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, dart-null-safety

I have been able to display JSON data from API in Future-builder. However, the widget has checkbox for each list. Whenever I check on one list, the whole list get checked. I want a help on how to check each list individually and be able to use the data of the selected list.

Comment: Can post your code with sample json data

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add a reference for each checkbox you want to be displayed.

First, create an empty list of booleans on your `Stateful` widget.

```
List<bool> _checkBoxValues = [];
```

Then for every item from your Api, add it on your `_checkBoxValues`.

```
bool x = false;
_checkBoxValues.add(x);
```

Then you access it using

```
return Checkbox(
        value: _checkBoxValues[index],
      ),
```